# Sql Sybase row count of distinct set of rows

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a table that contains a security_id and side (BUY or SELL) for every trade.  I want to count the number of distinct security_id and side combinations.

So when i do the following I get a list of all symbol sides but i don't know how to get a total count?

```
select 
  security_id, side
from 
  trade
group by security_id, side
```

The result i want is 1 row which tells me how many distinct security_id, side i have in the table.

Also is there a way to determine which security_id(s) have entries for both sides (BUY and SELL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select Count(*)
From    (
        Select security_id, side
        From trade
        Group security_id, side
        ) As Z
```

To the second question:

```
Select security_id
From trade
Where side In('BUY','SELL')
Group security_id
Having Count( Distinct side ) = 2
```

Comment: In the second question the OP is only asking about the IDs, not about their count. Still, your second query does include the solution (in the subquery).

Comment: @Andriy M - Ah. You are correct. I've updated the second query.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this?

```
select 
 security_id, side , count(*)
     from 
        trade
       group by security_id, side
```

Comment: that will give me the total for each security_id, side.  i want the total number of distinct security_id, side.

Comment: hmm .. I dont have a database handy to test it, but I'm sure the group by is essentially giving you a distinct combination of security_id and side.

Comment: I understand the question now.. you want to wrap your entire select with another select count(*) from ( select security_id, side ...group by ...)